# Python dictionary with list elements as keys and the elements of another list as the values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I would like to make a Python dictionary with the elements of one list as the keys and the list elements of another list as the values, is this possible?

So that:

```
list1 = ('red', 'blue', 'green', many more strings )
list2 = (1, 2, 3, many more values)

d = { list1[0:]: list2[0:] }
```

This obviously does not work, but something similar?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
>>> d = dict(zip(list1, list2))
{'blue': 2, 'green': 3, 'red': 1}
```

Comment: ok sorry, I really tried to find an answer but I guess I must've missed it! so funny that you can subtract reputation points, hilarious lol thank you for the answer! I will try this.